# MCTE doesn't work with clips loaded from an array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am using MCTE v3 (from JumpEye Components) in several Flash animations and originally had these animations loaded from a master "player" that loaded them remotely. Everything worked fine.

Now I have changed the master player to push each clip into an array and then play them (instead of loading and playing after each one ends)

But now the MCTE transitions are broken. The animation loads but several glitchy "placeholders" for MCTE can bee seen in the animation and the trace log shows errors along the lines of:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@2e704b31 to MCTEV3

Does anyone know why putting the clips into an array would break the transition components?

Comment: You should show some code - the error indicates you're trying to make the MCTEV3 object a MovieClip

Comment: I'm not touching MCTE at all. The animation containing MCTE works perfectly, both alone and when played via URLRequest straight to the swf file. Its now that I'm adding the swf to an array and then calling it that it is kicking off. I cannot really post any code as 1) there is a lot of different files and 2) its a sensitive project :/

Comment: How are you calling the swf?  Are you trying to make the swf a MovieClip?

Comment: I'm calling the remote swfs with a Loader() and then using "currentSWF = MovieClip(swfLoader.content);" (the Loader() is loading a URLRequest that points to the URL of the remote swf)

Comment: Try casting it as a DisplayObject instead

Comment: I tried "var currentSWF = DisplayObject(swfLoader.content);" but still same glitchy display issue and Type Coercion error

Comment: what happens if you don't cast it as anything and just load it as is?  I checked out the MCTE site - they're paid for components, so I can't help you there.  Do they have any samples of how to load things?  Or one other way would be to recreate the MCTE swf by making it a MovieClip and adding the plugin to that.